# Modify this regex to accept 0 to 15 characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex like this:

```
var filter = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/;
```

I want this regex to return true if there is no character on input field or if there is character less than 14. I tried using this:

```
var filter = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]{0, 15}*$/;
```

But this regex is never returning true. It always return false even after I satisfy the condition. What's wrong?

Comment: `{0,15}*` doesn't make much sense, think about it... You either match a specified number of characters or 0 or more.

Comment: @elclanrs: That would be illegal and should throw an error. His problem is that whitespace is significant in a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whitespace is significant in a regular expression. The space character makes your `{n,m}` quantifier invalid, causing `{0, 15}*` to be evaluated as the literal string `"{0, 15"`, followed by zero or more `}`s.

Also, you can condense `[A-Za-z0-9_]` into `\w`:

```
var filter = /^[ \w@./#&+-]{0,15}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.........

```
^\w{1,15}$
```